# Home Site is missing Global Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, communication-site

I have [enabled a Home Site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/home-site), but the global navigation does not show up. Does anyone know how to get it working? After a Home Site was setup, I was expecting this navigation piece to be visible somewhere, but it's nowhere to be seen.

**Steps performed**

- Enable Home site
- Waited for 1 hour

**PowerShell script used**

```
connect-SPOService -url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com
set-spohomesite -HomeSiteUrl https://contoso.sharepoint.com
```

[image: Home site]

**More details**

- Home site is a Communication site
- Tenant is setup with the targeted release
- [Build and launch a Microsoft SharePoint Home Site: Tips and Tricks From The Product Team](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBK32U7FRpU)
- [Set up a home site for your organization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/home-site)

Comment: Is the site a Hub site or connected to another Hub site?

Comment: Hi Callum. No. This site is a hub site

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem. I expected to have the global navigation option available in the settings cog, having seen it in a Microsoft demonstration video.

Comment: Judning by the official documentation, the demo from Ignite 2020 some features that were never implemented. Official documentation does not mention anything about global navigation.

Comment: I am facing the same issue over weeks now. Could you find out anything about a solution for this problem? Have you contacted MS support about it?

Comment: No, I didn't contact support. The global navigation showed up in my tenant about a week ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, capabilities of home site include:

1. Easily accessible from the SharePoint mobile app for Android and iOS
2. Search for the site is scoped to all sites within the organization
3. Automatically set up as an organization news site

Per my test there is also no "Global navigation settings" in my tenant(using targeted release), strangely I can't find any articles referred to this.

There may be some customization or new features that targeted release can not access, we suggest you raise a ticket from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Sharepoint admin area (not the sharepoint settings this is the administration centre for sharepoint) select settings and add your sharepoint URL in the Home Site area  - poss few hours to update

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I am not sure which step allowed me to enable global navigation, but I will list the steps that I performed.

The first thing I noticed was that I was not listed as the site owner for the Communications Site. I was working with the default Communications Site that was created with my account. A Service Account was listed as Site Owner of the original site, which I could not replace. **Please read through the rest of the instructions before following these steps.** I followed the instructions to replace my home page:

1. Go to the Active Sites page of the SharePoint Admin Center.
2. Select the root site (https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com).
3. Select 'Replace Site' in the navigation above.
4. Enter the URL of the site you want to use (/sites/yoursite).
5. Select Save.

- More information can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-root-site#replace-your-root-site

This did not enable Global Navigation, but it did set me as the Site Owner. **That was the part that I am not sure you will need to do**. Please be aware that the steps above will replace your existing root site.

Next, I set my 'home site' in the SharePoint Admin Center settings:

1. Go to the Settings page of the SharePoint Admin Center.
2. Select Home Site.
3. Paste the URL of the communication site that you want to become the home site (https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com).
4. Select Save.

Once this was complete, the 'replace site' option changed to 'change home site' when I selected the communications site on the active sites page of the SharePoint admin center. After opening the communications site for editing, the Global Navigation option was available in the settings.

**I would suggest trying to set your home page in the admin center settings first before replacing your root site!** I only included those steps because they were the steps that I took. I was just starting to create our intranet and did not have anything on the existing root site. I made this change because of a Note that I found on a page about enabling the Global Navigation:

**Site owner permissions (or higher) to the home site are required to enable global navigation.**

That Note can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/viva/connections/sharepoint-app-bar

I hope this helps others to be able to enable Global Navigation.